# Use of Past Simple vs Past perfect in sentences with since

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

> Ann admitted that she hadn't seen her parents **since she left** London.

Is the above sentence OK or do I have to write

> Ann admitted that she hadn't seen her parents **since she *had* left** London.

Comment: I don't know where these rules come from -- nobody ever quotes the rule they think they're following; they just assume that Somebody Up There Laid It Down, but they don't quite know where they laid it. Are we sure that we don't "have to write" _Ann had admitted that she hadn't seen her parents since she had left London_. Three hads are better than one or two.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine. The visit happened at a particular moment in time as well as Ann's admission. The activity or inactivity that pertains to the span **in-between** these two occurrences would in the active mood be written in present perfect. As you are supposed to shift the time backward in reported speech, though not in all cases, you use the past perfect.

*Ann admitted that since she left London **(reference point in time)** she had not visited her parents*.